# How to send data from a vb.net app to a web server?

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, web

The app I've created in visual studio gets its data from the users pc currently stores it in a text file uploads that to the server and this is how I get the data.  I was wondering if there is a way to have it send that same data without using text files but some kind of TCP connection maybe straight into a mysql server using php?  How would this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a simple **PHP web-service**, "uploaddata.php":

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["data"]))
    {
        echo("Saved these data: " . $_POST["data"]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: No data!";
    }
?>
```

And use it from your **VB.Net** using the **[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)**:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
wc.Headers("content-type") = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim response As String = wc.UploadString("http://localhost/uploaddata.php", "data=123" & Environment.NewLine & "456" & Environment.NewLine & "789")
MessageBox.Show(response)
```

Result:

```
Saved these data: 123
456
789
```

Comment: This seems to work fine on localhost (harddrive) but when it tries to upload to server it runs error.  (An exception during a Web Client Request. Content-Length or Chunked encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data.)

Comment: Maybe the server is sending a **redirect** to the client. You could check that with an HTTP debugger like **Fiddler** (http://fiddler2.com/).

Comment: i checked with fiddler and vb accessing files but not posting data,
if the code is
echo 'test'
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
 echo $_POST['data'];
}
it just outputs "test" even vb posting the $_POST['data']
"

Comment: With fiddler you can see the body of the POST request: do you see your payload, with your data?

Comment: I believe it may be a block from the webhost get error code 502, 500.

Comment: The server does not give more information? Do you connect directly to the server or from an intranet?

Comment: its a 3rd party hosting account that I am sending the information to.

Comment: So I guess they provide an HTML form for the "normal" upload of the file. Use a browser debugger like Firebug, or the one of your browser, and have a look at the "Network" tab to get the exact POST request sent by the form. If the form can upload you should be able to do the same, assuming there is no authentication or things like that. Because in this case you have to jump through more hoops. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution to a similar issue, I found Pragmateek's suggestion good. However, I used a variable WebBrowser and called the function Navigate passing as parameter the URL with the data I wanted to update on my database (hosted on a web server).

This is what I mean

```
Dim br As New WebBrowser
br.Navigate("http://yourwebsite/your-php-script.php?your_variable=" + the_data_you_want_to_send)
```

This is working well so far for me.. good luck!

Comment: But you should Check the response of the Webserver. Navigate could fail. So, pragmateeks approach is better and safer.